# Vanilla JavaScript Module Project: How to pass an array from child.js file to parent.js file

Tags: javascript, arrays, import, module

Array get`s updated often and I will have to make the updated array copy available to use in the parent component.

The key here is I was asked not to use the set Interval.

Is there any way to achieve this ? My project is a Vanilla JavaScript module type.

parent file say index.js and child file is main.js.

trying to get the array copied/cloned from main.js to index.js

Comment: Are events allowed? Are you allowed to pass a function to the child that it can call? Have you written any code at all?

Comment: Yes, I am creating a JavaScript library. I do have written code. So far I am importing functions from child to parent file and it will be consumed at parent file.. But for this one time I need updated Array from child to parent. if I import the file I will have the Array but I need the imported array to be updated as and when it gets updated in the child file.

Comment: sure, well, I gave you two options that don't require *set Interval*

Comment: hmmmm... I will try with the functions. Thanks for your time.